# Rails+AngularJSで、editablespanタグで囲まれた要素をinputタグではなくtextareaタグに置き換えたいです

Tags: javascript, angularjs

詰まってしまって困っているので質問させてください；；

AngularJSで編集可能なフィールドをつくり、Todoリスト名とTodoの内容を更新できるようにしたく、Editableなライブラリとして、[mkwidzinska/editablespan](https://github.com/mkwidzinska/editablespan) を採用しています。

editablespanタグで囲まれたテキストをクリックするとinputタグに置き換えられ変更可能になり、エンターキーで変更が確定されDBに保存させるところまでは実装できているのですが、できれば、inputタグではなくtextareaタグで同様のことを実現させたいです。

残念ながら仕様ではinputにしか対応しておらず、、配布元の、mkwidzinska/editablespanのドキュメントを読みJSFiddleでコードを変更しながらなんとか、テキストをクリックするとtextareaタグに置き換わるところまでは実現させることができたのですが、Enterを押すと改行になってしまい、変更が確定されません。

こちらの　[test shift+enter with angularjs - CodePen](http://codepen.io/y__b__y/pen/afFec?editors=101) も参考にしながら試行錯誤しているのですがどうしても実現させることがきなかったので質問させていただきました。どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

```
// directive code, scroll down for the controller!

/* mk.editablespan - v1.0.0 - 2013-08-26 */
var mod=angular.module("mk.editablespan",[]);mod.directive("editablespan",function(){return{restrict:"E",template:'<div><span ng-hide="editing" ng-class="spanClass">{{text}}</span><form ng-show="editing"><textarea  ng-class="inputClass"></textarea></form><div>',scope:{text:"=model",onReady:"&",spanClass:"@",inputClass:"@"},replace:!0,link:function(a,b){function c(){d(),h(!0),l[0].focus()}function d(){l.bind("blur",function(){f()}),l.bind("keyup",function(a){i(a)&&f()}),k.bind("submit",function(){l[0].value&&e(),f()})}function e(){a.text=l[0].value,a.$apply(),a.onReady()}function f(){g(),h(!1)}function g(){l.unbind(),k.unbind()}function h(b){a.editing=b,a.$apply()}function i(a){return a&&27==a.keyCode}var j=angular.element(b.children()[0]),k=angular.element(b.children()[1]),l=angular.element(b.children()[1][0]);j.bind("click",function(){l[0].value=a.text,c()})}}});

//---------------------------------------------------------

var app = angular.module('editApp', ['mk.editablespan']);

app.controller('editController', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {description: "This is a new item"};
  $scope.message = "";

  $scope.onReady = function(item) {
    $scope.message = "controller: edit ready, item description: " + item.description;
  };
});
```

Comment: 圧縮されたソースを貼られても読めませんよ。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

タグをtextareaに変えて、keyupイベントでshift-enterと同じキーコードのチェックをするようにしました。試してみると分かりますが、編集後の文字列が改行を含む場合でも１行で表示されるなど、不具合がありますので、改良が必要でしょう。

```
diff --git a/src/mk-editable-span.js b/src/mk-editable-span.js
index 00315cb..7e7d47f 100644
--- a/src/mk-editable-span.js
+++ b/src/mk-editable-span.js
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ var mod = angular.module('mk.editablespan', []);
 mod.directive('editablespan', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
-    template: '<div><span ng-hide="editing" ng-class="spanClass">{{text}}</span><form ng-show="editing"><input type="{{getInputType()}}" ng-class="inputClass"></form><div>',
+    template: '<div><span ng-hide="editing" ng-class="spanClass">{{text}}</span><form ng-show="editing"><textarea type="{{getInputType()}}" ng-class="inputClass"></textarea></form></div>',
     scope: {
       text: '=model',
       onReady: '&',
@@ -38,6 +38,14 @@ mod.directive('editablespan', function() {
         });

         input.bind('keyup', function(event) {
+         var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
+         if (code === 13) {
+             if (!event.shiftKey) {
+                 stopEdit();
+                 save();
+             }
+         }
+
           if(isEscape(event)) {
             stopEdit();
           }
```

Comment: ご返信が遅くなりすみません。教えていただいたコードで無事にやりたかったことを実現することができました。このコードから引続き機能実装をしていこうと思います。ありがとうございました。